# SSIS program in C# throwing lineageID not found

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have written an SSIS package in C# to get the data from a flat file to the database. The problem is that when i run the program through the SSIS interface then it is throwing error. If i just double click the derived column then it is refreshing the input column and running fine. Now my problem is I have to refresh the input column connection through C# program. How can this be done?

The following is the error which i am getting when i run the SSIS package through the cmd prompt.
Error: No Object exists which lineageID 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no object exists with lineageId 11, that means the package has been modified and the column has either been remapped with a different lineageId or removed.

In order to always have the correct lineageId, your code will need to [open and read the dtsx file and search by column name.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2008/08/01/how-to-find-out-which-column-caused-ssis-to-fail.aspx)